# Managed Pointer in a Structure C#

Tags: c#, pointers, structure, managed

i'm trying to write a generic function which should be able to parse a xml file

here is the code

```
    public struct XmlArg
    {
        public string Name;
        public Type T;
        public object Value;
    };

    static bool ParseXmlArgs(XmlReader xml, params XmlArg[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (xml.MoveToContent() != XmlNodeType.Element || xml.Name != args[i].Name)
            {
                return false;
            }
            args[i].Value = xml.ReadElementContentAs(args[i].T, null);
        }
        return true;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a = 0;

        ParseXmlArgs(
            XmlTextReader.Create("C:\\Users\\Yazilim\\Desktop\\XML.xml"),
            new XmlArg[]{
                new XmlArg() { Name = "ErrorCode", T = typeof(int), Value = a}});
    }
```

i know that i should pass a's pointer to Value ( it's type should be some different type other than object of course )

but i don't want it to be non-managed way.

is there any managed way to use a variable's pointer in structure ?

( the function may be wrong or incorrect, and it's not the point )

Comment: I don't understand why you need pointers, everything in C# is already reference type. Please explain better what are you trying to achieve and what is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want `XmlArg.Value` to *point* to `a` instead of just clone its value, then the answer is just "You can't". There is no address-of operator in C#, and that is for good reasons so, because you could create a reference to a variable on the stack (like your a is). When you run out of scope, that variable contains garbage and then ZONK.

Comment: so i should use unsafe context ?

Comment: That would be possible, but I really wouldn't do that, because it entirely breaks the safety of the .NET runtime. At the moment I cannot think of an easy solution for your problem :-(

Comment: I suggest you go over [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420186/references-to-variables-in-c) question. There are some hints of working around this limitation. For instance, if your `a` wasn't a value but a reference type, your code would work just fine.

Comment: thanks, link you gave is exactly what i'm looking for but unfortunately there is no simple answer :(

Answer (score 0):

Check this one out :[Struct Pointer Initialization in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687529/struct-pointer-initialization-in-c-sharp).

Also, from the Microsoft docs regarding structs :Structs can also contain constructors, constants, fields, methods, properties, indexers, operators, events, and nested types, although if several such members are required, you should consider making your type a class instead.

Hope that helps!