# How do you extract data from a C++ library to a struct pointer in C#

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, struct, interop

I have a third party library and their C# wrapper was just a minimal list of `DLLImport` from their C++ library. There is a method I am trying to use that is passing data like this

```cpp
public static extern ErrorResult GetData(void* pData)
```

I know the data is a struct, and they do provide the struct with the `StructLayout` attributes to make it explicit in size similar to below

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 120)]
unsafe public struct DataStruct
{
    //stuff
}
```

I'm trying to do this

```cs
unsafe
{
    DataStruct* data;
    var error = Wrapper.GetData(data);
}
```

but this errors saying that data is unassigned `CS0165 use of unassigned local variable 'data'`

I tried to initialize data, and I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8687529/4708150), but the answer just says don't do this in C#, but I don't have control over the third party API that I'm using and need to extract the data how they have it set up and documentation and examples are sparse.

Others on that question suggested `stackalloc`, but I'm not sure what what that would look like in the case of a struct.

Comment: Can you not simply add `public static extern ErrorResult GetData(ref DataStruct pData)`?

Comment: @GSerg the public static extern here is referencing a method in an external C++ library, and the signature of that method uses a `void*`, can you really just replace `void*` with ref and it automagically work? Also, the return type is not always `DataStruct`, but could be different types of structs depending on other parameters that you pass. I simplified the question above and removed a lot of the additional parameters.

Comment: Of course you can. That's the point of it. It's all `void*` under the hood. Add a separate `public static extern ErrorResult GetData` for each of the possible types that can go as the argument, too. And most likely you don't need the `unsafe` on the struct either. Just also decorate it with appropriate marshaling attributes.

Comment: Ask them to write a proper wrapper using C++/cli. C++ hardly ever should be exposed to void* (except in some rare type erasure scenarios). In any case I will not trust pointers passed by .Net into C++. Either pin the pointers (so garbage collector cannot move/delete) and/or copy the data as soon as you can to unmanaged (c++ heap) memory. ([C++/cli introduction](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to test with the hardware I am working with, and I can confirm that changing the wrapper signature to be the below does work.

```cs
public static extern ErrorResult GetData(ref DataStruct data)
```

In my scenario the type of struct returned can change, but that's also an easy fix as overloads can be added for the different struct types supported

```cs
public static extern ErrorResult GetData(ref DifferentDataStruct data)
```

Answer (score 1):

While typing up my question, I think I figured out how to use stackalloc to get what I need

```cs
unsafe
{
    var dataPointer = stackalloc byte[sizeof(DataStruct)];
    var error = Wrapper.GetData(dataPointer);
    var data = (DataStruct*)dataPointer;
    Console.WriteLine(data->SomeProperty);
}
```

Not sure if there are any better ways of handling this.